# How to I stop Vista from pulsating my focused XAML buttons?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, focus, styles

I've created a style for buttons in my WPF application.

However, on Vista, when a button is focused, it **pulsates with a light blue** that doesn't look good in the design.

**How can I override this automatic pulsating?**

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#aaa"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ddd" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#aaa" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### Tried "IsFocused":

Adding this doesn't have any effect on Vista, the button still looks the same and is pulsating in Vista when focused:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Trigger>
```

#### Tried "ControlTemplate" solution:

Still no effect:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="NavigationButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#aaa"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ddd" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#aaa" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is being set in response IsKeyboardFocused, not just standard focus.

In Blend if you edit the control template for a standard button, you'll see that on the IsKeyboardFocused=true trigger is responsible for this effect.

```
<Style x:Key="Button_NonGlow" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the IsFocused trigger property.  Sorry that I do not have a working example for you right here.

---

UPDATE:

I found this small piece of code that I once used.  I am not sure if is works and I can not test it (I am on an XP box):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried the "IsFocused" code above but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example using FocusVisualStyle instead of IsFocused.

Comment: tried that as well (posted code above) but the button just continues to pulsate light blue to gray

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific requirements you can simply ensure the button never gets keyboard focus by setting IsTabStop="False" and IsDefault="False".